# Mono 3.12.1 running .Net 2.0 app: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, monodevelop

A .NET 2.0 framework Standard project (Quite old dlls)

I have ran the same project on windows MS visual studio it compiled successfully and ran successfully. However, on linux monodevelop it compiles successfully but raised a run exception :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type  
Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsControlSystem' from assembly 
Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface, Version=1.4.1404.401, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not 
load type 'Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsControlSystem' from assembly 
Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface, Version=1.4.1404.401, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

It's my first attempt with .NET stuff. I believe there is a problem in running the references. However, couldn't find out why?.

Note:
mono target platform compilation: .NET 2.0
project : .NET 2.0

**UPDATE**

I ran the following command to log more informations:
    `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono Test.exe`

The output:

```
    Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x2335be0] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll[0x2334cd0]: 2
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x2335be0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'Test.exe'.
Mono: Image addref Test[0x239f410] -> /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe[0x2333880]: 3
Mono: Assembly Test[0x239f410] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'Test.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Test/Test.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'Test.exe'.
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290] -> /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll[0x23a1890]: 2
Mono: Assembly Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle/Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290]: 2
Mono: The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 3
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll[0x23a7f10]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 4
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System[0x23bab00] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll[0x23b9990]: 2
Mono: Assembly System[0x23bab00] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> System[0x23bab00]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System[0x23bab00] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 5
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Drawing[0x23cdae0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll[0x23ccba0]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Drawing[0x23cdae0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Drawing/System.Drawing.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> System.Drawing[0x23cdae0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Drawing[0x23cdae0] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 6
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Accessibility[0x23d3b10] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll[0x23d2c60]: 2
Mono: Assembly Accessibility[0x23d3b10] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Accessibility/Accessibility.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> Accessibility[0x23d3b10]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface[0x23e9350] -> /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll[0x23e80f0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface[0x23e9350] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface/Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface[0x23e9350]: 2
Mono: The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Nova.Mars.SDK.MarsInterface[0x23e9350] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 7
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290] -> System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0]: 3
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass[0x23ebba0] -> /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll[0x23ea850]: 2
Mono: Assembly Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass[0x23ebba0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass/Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass[0x23ebba0]: 2
Mono: The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Nova.LCT.GigabitSystem.DataClass[0x23ebba0] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 8
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Test[0x239f410] -> System[0x23bab00]: 3
Mono: The request to load the assembly System v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Nova.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandle[0x23a7290] -> System[0x23bab00]: 4
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/UIAutomationWinforms/1.0.0.0__f4ceacb585d99812/UIAutomationWinforms.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/UIAutomationWinforms.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/UIAutomationWinforms.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/UIAutomationWinforms/1.0.0.0__f4ceacb585d99812/UIAutomationWinforms.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/UIAutomationWinforms.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/UIAutomationWinforms.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Mono.Posix[0x2442680] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll[0x24417a0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Mono.Posix[0x2442680] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Posix/Mono.Posix.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms[0x23acea0] -> Mono.Posix[0x2442680]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Posix[0x2442680] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 9
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libc.so.6': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libc.so.6.so': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libc.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libc.so.6' ('libc.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'uname'.
Mono: Probing 'uname'.
Mono: Found as 'uname'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XInitThreads'.
Mono: Probing 'XInitThreads'.
Mono: Found as 'XInitThreads'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XOpenDisplay'.
Mono: Probing 'XOpenDisplay'.
Mono: Found as 'XOpenDisplay'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat'.
Mono: Probing 'XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat'.
Mono: Found as 'XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XSetErrorHandler'.
Mono: Probing 'XSetErrorHandler'.
Mono: Found as 'XSetErrorHandler'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XDestroyWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XDestroyWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XDestroyWindow'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XCloseDisplay'.
Mono: Probing 'XCloseDisplay'.
Mono: Found as 'XCloseDisplay'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XQueryExtension'.
Mono: Probing 'XQueryExtension'.
Mono: Found as 'XQueryExtension'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XSynchronize'.
Mono: Probing 'XSynchronize'.
Mono: Found as 'XSynchronize'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XDefaultScreen'.
Mono: Probing 'XDefaultScreen'.
Mono: Found as 'XDefaultScreen'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XRootWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XRootWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XRootWindow'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XDefaultColormap'.
Mono: Probing 'XDefaultColormap'.
Mono: Found as 'XDefaultColormap'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XCreateSimpleWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XCreateSimpleWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XCreateSimpleWindow'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XConnectionNumber'.
Mono: Probing 'XConnectionNumber'.
Mono: Found as 'XConnectionNumber'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XSelectInput'.
Mono: Probing 'XSelectInput'.
Mono: Found as 'XSelectInput'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libc.so.6': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libc.so.6.so': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libc.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libc.so.6' ('libc.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'uname'.
Mono: Probing 'uname'.
Mono: Found as 'uname'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdiplusStartup'.
Mono: Probing 'GdiplusStartup'.
Mono: Found as 'GdiplusStartup'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Configuration[0x24e37c0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll[0x248c460]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Configuration[0x24e37c0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System[0x23bab00] -> System.Configuration[0x24e37c0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Configuration[0x24e37c0] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 10
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Configuration[0x24e37c0] -> System[0x23bab00]: 5
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Xml[0x24f1dc0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll[0x24f1060]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Xml[0x24f1dc0] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Configuration[0x24e37c0] -> System.Xml[0x24f1dc0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0x24f1dc0] -> mscorlib[0x2335be0]: 11
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0x24f1dc0] -> System[0x23bab00]: 6
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System[0x23bab00] -> System.Xml[0x24f1dc0]: 3
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XDisplayKeycodes'.
Mono: Probing 'XDisplayKeycodes'.
Mono: Found as 'XDisplayKeycodes'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XGetKeyboardMapping'.
Mono: Probing 'XGetKeyboardMapping'.
Mono: Found as 'XGetKeyboardMapping'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XFree'.
Mono: Probing 'XFree'.
Mono: Found as 'XFree'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XGetModifierMapping'.
Mono: Probing 'XGetModifierMapping'.
Mono: Found as 'XGetModifierMapping'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XKeycodeToKeysym'.
Mono: Probing 'XKeycodeToKeysym'.
Mono: Found as 'XKeycodeToKeysym'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XFreeModifiermap'.
Mono: Probing 'XFreeModifiermap'.
Mono: Found as 'XFreeModifiermap'.
Mono: The request to load the assembly mscorlib v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Windows.Forms v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: The request to load the assembly mscorlib v1.0.5000.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'Xutf8LookupString'.
Mono: Probing 'Xutf8LookupString'.
Mono: Found as 'Xutf8LookupString'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XLookupString'.
Mono: Probing 'XLookupString'.
Mono: Found as 'XLookupString'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XSupportsLocale'.
Mono: Probing 'XSupportsLocale'.
Mono: Found as 'XSupportsLocale'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XSetLocaleModifiers'.
Mono: Probing 'XSetLocaleModifiers'.
Mono: Found as 'XSetLocaleModifiers'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XOpenIM'.
Mono: Probing 'XOpenIM'.
Mono: Found as 'XOpenIM'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XInternAtom'.
Mono: Probing 'XInternAtom'.
Mono: Found as 'XInternAtom'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libX11.so.6' ('libX11.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'XInternAtoms'.
Mono: Probing 'XInternAtoms'.
Mono: Found as 'XInternAtoms'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.so': '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' ('libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'gtk_invisible_new'.
Mono: Probing 'gtk_invisible_new'.
Mono: Found as 'gtk_invisible_new'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' ('libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'gtk_widget_ensure_style'.
Mono: Probing 'gtk_widget_ensure_style'.
Mono: Found as 'gtk_widget_ensure_style'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' ('libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'gtk_widget_get_style'.
Mono: Probing 'gtk_widget_get_style'.
Mono: Found as 'gtk_widget_get_style'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' ('libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'gtk_menu_new'.
Mono: Probing 'gtk_menu_new'.
Mono: Found as 'gtk_menu_new'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' ('libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'gtk_init_check'.
Mono: Probing 'gtk_init_check'.
Mono: Found as 'gtk_init_check'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipCreateStringFormat'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipCreateStringFormat'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipCreateStringFormat'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Drawing[0x23cdae0] -> System[0x23bab00]: 7
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipSetStringFormatLineAlign'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipSetStringFormatLineAlign'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipSetStringFormatLineAlign'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipSetStringFormatAlign'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipSetStringFormatAlign'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipSetStringFormatAlign'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipSetStringFormatHotkeyPrefix'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipSetStringFormatHotkeyPrefix'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipSetStringFormatHotkeyPrefix'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipSetStringFormatTabStops'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipSetStringFormatTabStops'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipSetStringFormatTabStops'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipGetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipGetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipGetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libgdiplus.so.0' ('libgdiplus.so.0').
Mono: Searching for 'GdipSetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipSetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipSetStringFormatFlags'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Control.CrystalButton.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Nova.Control.CrystalButton[0x244ef00] -> /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Control.CrystalButton.dll[0x244e180]: 2
Mono: Assembly Nova.Control.CrystalButton[0x244ef00] added to domain Test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Control.CrystalButton.dll.so' not found: /home/hd/Documents/VMS-PROJECT/NovaStar/SDK/SDK/Sample/C/Test/bin/Debug/Nova.Control.CrystalButton.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Update 2**
[image: dlls with ILSpy]

Comment: You must edit your question once again. The reference list shows a ".NET Framework 2.0" library with dependencies that are very likely to be Windows only. Thus, please remove terms like "standard" from the question, as you don't use .NET Standard. Windows apps cannot run on Linux via Mono, as Mono is designed not for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I will try run the app on wine, the supplier does not have linux api for his product. So I must use the windows stuff.